# How do I add additional compiler switches in Visual Studio

Tags: visualstudio

Using Visual Studio to program my Arduino. I want to add additional compiler switches and include paths.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ExtraFlags in the project properties. The flags can be specified for the currently selected configuration or for all builds of the current project.

The feature was released in the 15.06 version of the [Visual Micro](http://www.visualmicro.com) Arduino plugin for Visual Studio.

This [guide](http://www.visualmicro.com/page/User-Guide.aspx?doc=Project-Properties-Reference.html) shows how to access the project properties