# How to exclude a ino/pde file from Arduino projects

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, sketch, visualstudio, ino

I would like to be able to exclude from the auto-including process of the current project (without renaming the extension or delete it) a sketch with `pde` or `ino` extension that is used in certain circumstances only.

How can I do this?

I currently use Visual Micro to manage projects on Arduino.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach is to guard the body of that sketch with an `#ifdef ... #endif` pair, and use Visual Micro's  “Project Properties” to define (or not) a preprocessor symbol.  [If the .ino or .pde in question is used as a `#include` file, you would instead guard all the `#include` instances.]

Refer to the [“Project Defines”](http://www.visualmicro.com/page/User-Guide.aspx?doc=Project-Defines.html) page at visualmicro.com for how to define a preprocessor symbol and its value. [Via: Tools > Options > Visual Micro > Compiler > Show Build Properties]  Also see  [How do I add additional compiler switches in Visual Studio](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/13105).

If necessary, you can use other tests besides `#ifdef` to control compilation.  The first link above shows the following example.

```
#if USBPORT > 3
....your code here....
#endif
```